# How to use "sich"

Tags: meaning, reflexive

I get confused each time I see **sich** in a sentence.

I know it's used with [reflexive verbs](http://german.about.com/library/weekly/aa022601b.htm), but the problem is sometimes I cannot convince myself of the way it's used. Examples like:

> In der Presse wie auch im Fernsehen finden sich zunehmend Meldungen über die verheerenden Folgen des Spielens am Computer.
>
> Eine Klasse für sich
>
> Frauen unter sich
>
> Deutschland schafft sich ab.

I found it really hard to explain what's the meaning of "sich" and what are rules about its usage, are there any rules which replies to my question?

Comment: How not to use »sich«: http://images05.noen.at/online-wahlplakat-fpoe-horn-2sp-top.jpg/1920x1080/4.318.915 »Wir setzen sich ein dass der Kindergarten in Breiteneich erhalten bleibt« (This would be correct: »Wir setzen uns dafür ein, dass der Kindergarten in Breiteneich erhalten bleibt.«)

Comment: @Hubert the FPÖ poster even says »das der Kindergarten« (which is wrong) :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"sich" can often be translated to "himself/herself/itself, themselves" (*) or "each other", which covers all but one of your examples:

> Eine Klasse für sich. -> A class of its own (or, literally, by itself).
>
> Frauen unter sich. -> Women among themselves.
>
> Deutschland schafft sich ab. -> Germany abolishes itself.

Your first example is a different breed though:

> In der Presse wie auch im Fernsehen **finden sich** zunehmend Meldungen über die verheerenden Folgen des Spielens am Computer. -> In the press and on TV, more and more reports on the devastating effects of PC games **can be found**.

This is the *reflexive form of "finden"* which is used here as a figure of speech to avoid an acting person in the sentence, very much in the same way as *the passive voice* is used in its English equivalent. "Sich" can only be used though with reflexive verbs.

---

(*) cf. "mich" - "myself", "dich" - "yourself", "uns" - "ourselves", "euch" - "yourselves"