# What does "Sich" mean and how is it used in a sentence?

Tags: pronoun

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use “sich”](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2902/how-to-use-sich)

I realize this is  a pretty basic question, but I can't wrap my head around "Sich".
I know it technically means "self", but how is it used in everyday speech/writing?

Comment: Lets close this, didn't see that one. Thanks