# On word order in this type of context

Tags: grammar, word-order

If I want to say, *I want to show it to you*, do I say, *Ich will **dir es** zeigen*, or, *Ich will **es dir** zeigen*?

Which is the grammatically correct word order?

(I'm mainly interested in how the formal version of the language uses this construction.)

Based on other similar examples which I've lately been reading, I would say the correct version is the first one, with the indirect object coming straight after the main verb, but I'm still not sure if that is the case, which is why I'm asking you.

Comment: You might be interested into the article [Ob { Klara ihn | ihn Klara } liebte?](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/wortstellung-reflexivpronomen-personalpronomen.php)

Comment: es dir is the default... "dir es" works if you have a very good reason for it

Comment: Another question on this topic: [Where to place “sich” in an elaborate sentence?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/6474/1224)

Answer (score 4):

The correct version is the second:

> Ich will es dir zeigen

When the objects are pronominalized (personal pronouns, not demonstrative ones) the *Akkusativobjekt* usually goes before the *Dativ*.

Quelle: [Link](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Wortstellung/Stellungsfeld/Mittelfeld/Objekt.html)

Comment: That is only partially correct... if the pronoun is das instead of es situation changes and dir comes first

Comment: @Emanuel Since it says "usually" this doesn't make my statement less correct, but you are right, of course. You are free to edit my answer or add a more complete answer yourself. I'm sure this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Ok, the [rule](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/wortstellung-reflexivpronomen-personalpronomen.php) says "Pronomen vor dem Substantiv", and if this doesn't help (because both implied words are nouns or both pronouns), then one chooses according to "Subjekt-Dativ-Objekt". So @Emanuel, are you saying that in `Ich will dir das zeigen`, `das` is the object (but in the original sentence `es` was `subjekt`). Am I right?

Comment: There is not really a rule... there are just tendencies: - if both are nouns - first dat then acc; if one is pronoun - pron. first; if both are personal pronouns - acc first; if one pronoun is demonstrative - first dat... I recommend not thinking in rules when it comes to word order because German doesn't work that way

Comment: @c.p. 'es' is not subject on the original sentence, Emanuel didn't say that. 'es' and 'das' are both Akkusativobjekt.

Comment: @bouscher sorry, I got confused by the example *An der Tür umarmte er(=Subjekt) Helga (=Objekt) zum letzten­mal.*, in the link of my last comment. Indeed, *ich* is the subject in any sentence, I meant "es" is the object.