# The position of the reflexive pronoun "sich" in a rather long subordinate clause

Tags: word-order, reflexive

Is it more natural (or easier) to say:

> ... , **wenn** zwei Menschen von unterschiedlichem Range **sich** einen Eheschwur **leisten**!?

rather than:

> ... , **wenn** **sich** zwei Menschen von unterschiedlichem Range einen Eheschwur **leisten**!?

---

I have already referred to some enlightening past posts, notably [this one](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6474/where-to-place-sich-in-an-elaborate-sentence/6513#6513), but there still remains one point that I hope to clarify.

When a subordinate clause is relatively long and you place *sich* immediately after a conjunction, it does not seem easy to keep track of the relation between *sich* and the verb *leisten* placed at the end.

As a non-native speaker, I'm more inclined to put *sich* closer to *leisten*, but how do native speakers think about this?

Comment: Maybe this question already has an answer [here](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6474/where-to-place-sich-in-an-elaborate-sentence).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a question of style. Both variants are accepted. Due to my gut-feeling I'd say, that the second variant, with the "sich" at the earliest position, would sound more natural.

But these are stylistic nuances. The German philosopher Theodor W. Adorno, for instance, got some ambivalent fame for his mannerism to usually put the reflexive pronoun in the *last* position possible.

Comment: Even though you've rejected my edit, "stylistic" is still a -t- short in your text.