# Position von Reflexivpronomen

Tags: word-order, pronoun, reflexive

Warum ist die Position vom Reflexivpronomen in den Beispielen 1 und 2 verschieden (ein Lehrbuchbeispiel)? Ist 3 auch richtig oder ist es nicht so richtig wie 1? Kann das jemand erklären?

```
1. Hat sich Kathrin gefreut?
2. Hat sie sich gefreut?
3. Hat Kathrin sich gefreut?
```

Comment: Es gibt eine Antwort [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6474/where-to-place-sich-in-an-elaborate-sentence), allerdings auf Englisch.

Answer (score 1):

Das Reflexivpronomen "sich" ist faktisch  das Objekt deiner Beispielsätze. Es kann also alle Positionen einnehmen, die das Objekt in einem "normalen", nichtreflexiven Satz einnehmen kann.

Da "sich" klar Objektfunktion wahrnimmt, kann es auch Positionen einnehmen, die ansonsten einen Satz mißverständlich machen würden (dein Beispiel 1) und deshalb eher ungewöhnliche (aber durchaus "richtige") Positionen für ein Objekt sind.