Why does "sich" precede "Personen" in this sentence?
I saw this sentence online, apparently from a native speaker:

Anfreunden ist, wenn sich Personen gut verstehen und Freunde werden. (source)

Why is it not

Anfreunden ist, wenn Personen sich gut verstehen und Freunde werden.

I understand in a dependent clause led by "wenn" the main verb goes to the end but shouldn't the rest still follow declarative sentence order? I thought reflexive pronouns would always come after the nominative subject.

What do you mean by 'declarative sentence order'? As for reflexive pronouns always coming after the nominative subject, that's simply wrong, there is no such rule.

Similar question: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6474/where-to-place-sich-in-an-elaborate-sentence/6513#6513

Note that the position of "sich" is quite variable, and putting it later tends to sound more formal, as satiricised here: http://www.zweitgeist.net/2010/01/das-postponierte-reflexivum/

They are both grammatical. Word order in German is fairly flexible apart from the positioning of the verb, which is unaffected by this.

indeed my preferred choice (for unknown reasons) is the version suggested by the OP. Maybe because it puts the emphasis on the subject topic of the subordinate clause (Personen), or maybe because it better fits a rythm or stressed and unstressed sylables.

it feels like the focus is a bit different - the source-version starts with (the first part of) "sich verstehen", so the focus is more on that part. The OP version starts with "Personen", so the focus is more on that - so if I thought about grammar when building my sentences, I might choose one or the other depending on what I consider more important for the understanding of the recipient.

@Syndic in both examples given, the focus is clearly on "sich verstehen". Why would the focus be on "Personen"? That wouldn't make sense in this context. So it's only logical to put the "sich" as early as possible by your reasoning.

Would I be correctly in thinking that the version with the reflexive before the subject would not be grammatical if the subject were a pronoun? For example, “Anfreunden ist, wenn sich sie gut verstehen und Freunde werden” would be ungrammatical, right?

@JanusBahsJacquet that sounds very odd and unnatural, I am not sure if it is technically grammatical

@Joooeey what I mean is... the first one sounds like "befriending is when people get along well and become friends" (I would prefer this if I wanted to explain that they have to get along first), the second one "befriending is when people get along well and become friends" (preferred if you were to explain to a child that rocks can't become friends, only people. But why would you, let the kid play pretend!). Purely based on how the variants feel when I try to make out a difference - grammatically both are fine.
