# How to use properly "sich selbst"

Tags: meaning, difference, grammar-identification

I would like to understand why do I need to add the *selbst* to the word *sich* in this sentence:

> Ergänzen Sie den Steckbrief und schreiben Sie einen Text über sich selbst.

In my mind it would be enough to finish this sentence with only

> ...einen Text über sich.

I need examples that support the explanation to understand it properly

Related topic:
[How to use "sich"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2902/how-to-use-sich)

Comment: It's just like in English: Write a text about you / Write a text about yourself.

Comment: Did you notice how odd the redundancy in "\* ... him, he who ..." is? Of course it's redundant and you can drop the *he*, but *him whom* sounds bad if not wrong, whereas *him who* lacks agreement in the antecedent. Now how to connect this to the question? *se* had been a pronoun in OE similar to *him* or *sich*, when the language was still strongly self reflexive; Analoguously, *beschreiben Sie sich* would just mean *beschreiben Sie* (cp. *raffen Sie sich auf*); One would have to ask *was soll ich mir beschreiben?*. Although, "\* schreiben Sie sich einen Text über selbst" is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both sentences convey the same meaning and I wouldn't be surprised if I read either one, meaning that there is no "need to add the *selbst*".

One could argue, however, that the two sentences have a different emphasis. The version without *selbst* emphasizes the text, whereas the version with *selbst* emphasizes the topic of the text.

Comment: Good idea. To add examples, consider "schreiben Sie selbst einen Text über sich", which emphasises doing it alone, giving a self-reflected opinion. We would also say "Schreiben Sie einen Text über sich. Schreiben Sie den Text selbst [alleine, ohne Hilfe]". "Selber über sich schreiben ist schwierig". I'm not sure whether only I am conflating *selber* and *selbst*, or if this is common practice. One might add that determinative *derselbe*, *denselben*, etc. is the sameone self-same redundancy.

Answer (score 2):

There is no change in meaning, but *selbst* puts more emphasis on *sich*.

> Andere bevorzugen Bier, ich [selbst] trinke lieber Wein.

When spoken, *selbst* gets a notable stress.

Comment: So in sumary, in written german if you add "selbst"  to "sich" it doesn't make a difference in the overall meaning. But when spoken the selbst stresses the word sich ? @guidot

Answer (score 0):

Guidots answer gives me the idea that in spoken German the word '**sich**' (without '*selbst*') would be emphasized (stressed):

> [*spoken*] Schreiben Sie etwas über **sich**.

This is not possible in written language. So I think '**sich selbst**' is just a written workaround for spoken stress.