# When to use sich?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-structure, reflexive

I have this sentence in english `Let's buy it (to us)!`.
In my workbook, translation of this sentence is following : `Kaufen wir es uns!`

My question is : Can I also use `Kaufen wir es sich!`?
I have already visited this [question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2902/how-to-use-sich), but that does not explain if I can freely switch `sich` and the  **pronoun in dative case**

Comment: The more literal translation from Let's (let us) buy it, would be "lass es uns kaufen".

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reflexive pronouns in German are (accusative/dative where they differ):

- singular: mich/mir, dich/dir, sich
- plural: uns, euch, sich

So "sich" is only used in the third person.

- Ich kaufe mir ein Buch.
- Du kaufst dir ein Buch.
- Er kauft sich ein Buch.
- Wir kaufen uns ein Buch.
- Ihr kauft euch ein Buch.
- Sie kaufen sich ein Buch.

And of course, you can also buy books for someone else: Du kaufst mir ein Buch. (Danke!)

Comment: So I can't say "Kauf sich etwas !" can I ?

Comment: No, that would be "Kauf Dir etwas!"

Comment: Thank you a lot !

Answer (score 1):

No, this does not work.

It is tricky, because the infinitive form found in the dictionary

> *sich etwas kaufen*

uses *sich*, but this has to be replaced by the appropriate personal pronoun, matching the earlier occurrence, which in the example case requires the plural *uns*. *Sich* is either singular or third person plural and would not match grammatically.

The full list is: ich/mir, du/dir, er-sie-es/sich, wir/uns, ihr/euch, sie/sich.

It is of course possible to buy something for somebody else, as in

> Wir kaufen ihm/dir/mir etwas.

but as I understand this is not the scope of your question.

Comment: So, if I understand it right, I can say "Kauf sich etwas" but not "Kaufen wir sich etwas" ?

Comment: To Cesar you might say "Kauf er sich etwas!", but otherwise the imperative sing. demands "dir": "Kauf dir was!"  / "Kauft euch was!"